# Python: Sorting Tuples in array based off first element

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, file-io, tuples

I had a file with records (`highscores`) stored as an `int` on each line (with a header).

In my python project I was reading the records into an array, then adding a record (just an `int`), sorting the array (with the new record added) and then overwriting the file with the new records (and header - which remained the same)

Here is the relevant code I used for that:

```
highscores = []
with open("highscore.txt", "r") as f:
    f.readline() # Reads header
    for line in f:
        highscores.append(line.strip())

highscores.append(wins)
highscores = sorted(highscores, key=int, reverse=True)
# Print sorted highscores print to file
with open("highscore.txt", "w") as f:
  for val in highscores:
    print(val, file=f)
```

Now I have a file with records stored in the form `int /t string` on each line (with a header).  I'm not experienced in reading or sorting arrays with tuples and have no idea on how to approach this.  Could anyone set me on the right path or provide a solution.

I'd like to read the `int /t string` record from my file and put it into the `highscores` array.  Then I'd like to sort the array based off of the `int` value which is the first element of the tuple (assuming I don't take another approach).  Then overwriting the file with the new `highscore` records.

Edit:

I should not that when I wrote`highscore.append(wins)`, wins is an integer variable I would like to append wins and name (the string as my variable).

Comment: Have a look at [split](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change much:

```
 highscores = sorted(highscores, key=lambda s: int(s.split()[0]), reverse=True)
```

The key function will take your line `s`. Then it will split it, take the first part and then convert it to an integer.

Comment: Well that solves my sorting problem (easy fix) thank you! :)  But I also need to change it to read and write from and to the file respectively.

Comment: I believe no other change is needed. What isn't done with this *fix*?

Comment: When I said `highscores.append(wins)`, that put wins (which is an int) into the array, I also need to add a variable called name as the string to the array, how do I append that?  Editing question now to be more specific.

Comment: Would I just do that using `highscores.append(str(wins) + '\t' + name)`?

I'm going to try that, and if it all works I'll accept your answer, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Try `str(wins) + '\t' + name`